# How to translate i18n Plone actions.xml

Tags: internationalization, plone

How can I use/translate the (url_expr/available_expr) in actions.xml?

My usual way was to make a seperate "object" for each language:

```
<object name="contact" meta_type="CMF Action" i18n:domain="my.theme">
 <property name="title" i18n:translate="">Contact</property>
 <property name="description" i18n:translate=""></property>
 <property
  name="url_expr">string:${globals_view/navigationRootUrl}/contact</property>
 <property name="icon_expr"></property>
 <property name="available_expr">python:request.LANGUAGE == 'en'</property>
</object>

<object name="contact-de" meta_type="CMF Action" i18n:domain="my.theme">
 <property name="title" i18n:translate="">Contact</property>
 <property name="description" i18n:translate=""></property>
 <property
  name="url_expr">string:${globals_view/navigationRootUrl}/kontakt</property>
 <property name="icon_expr"></property>
 <property name="available_expr">python:request.LANGUAGE == 'de'</property>
</object>
```

Comment: Do you have LinguaPlone installed to handle the translation between `contact` and `kontakt`?

Comment: Yes, Products.LinguaPlone 4.0.4 with language-folders  
(de/en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `contact` / `kontakt` content is multilingual content managed by LinguaPlone, you can use the [`takeaction` add-on](http://plone.org/products/takeaction) to create *one* action that'll switch between translations as needed.

`takeaction` has it's own configuration file, like `actions.xml` it is a Generic Setup file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_takeaction"
   meta_type="TakeAction content-as-actions tool">
  <item category="site_actions" path="en/contact" />
</object>
```

The above configuration designates a content object at `en/contact` as a `site_actions` action item. It'll be listed in that action category, taking the title and description of one of the translations of the content object matching the current language.

You do *not* list the action in `actions.xml` anymore; the `takeaction` tool is itself a action provider.

Disclaimer: I am the original author of `takeaction`.